# Form submit page refreshes

Tags: javascript, jquery

Yeah, I know. There are loads of similar questions out there, but I've tried most of the provided methods. `return false;` nor `e.preventDefault` works for me.

This is the piece of Javascript (jQuery) I used:

```
$(document).on("submit", "#chat-form", function() {     
    var chatMessage = $(".chat-input").val();

    console.log(chatMessage);

    send({
        "type": "chat",
        "msg": msg
    });

    return false;
});
```

EDIT: **Solved** `msg` wasn't defined, and should of been `chatMessage`

Comment: @Lixus please read the post..

Comment: my guess there is an error.... anything in the console if you click the preserve button.

Comment: What is `send()`?

Comment: @epascarello users can use the enter button to submit.

Comment: @Lixus it's sends a signal using socketio to the nodejs server, I'm building a chat.

Comment: What does enter key have to do with what I said?

Comment: that is not a valid Ajax request if that is what you are trying to do and `e.preventDefault()` works. Maybe you forgot to put `function(e)` before.

Comment: @hansTheFranz nope, I did it the correct way, unfortunately :(

Comment: @CS-CASES.org use a breakpoint, step through the code, and then look for errors?

Comment: So you click the button in the console to preserve the log....

Comment: @epascarello ugh ugh ugh, thanks a lot, I didn't even know this function existed.

Comment: Problem was, I didn't define `msg`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In `send` function you are using `msg` variable which is not defined. use `chatMessage` instead and it will work fine.

```js
$(document).on("submit", "#chat-form", function(e) {
    var chatMessage = $(".chat-input").val();

    console.log(chatMessage);

    send({
        "type": "chat",
        "msg": chatMessage
    });

  return false;
});


function send(data) {}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="chat-form">
chat: <input class="chat-input" />
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: That was indeed the problem, I already solved it like a few seconds ago, but I will accept this as an anwser.

Edit: why did this get downvoted?

Comment: yeah, true. might of not been my smartest question but this question also gained me 3 downvotes, great.